# Can you identify this minifigure with green skin and red hat?

Tags: minifigures, minifigure-identification

I would like to know who this minifigure is or what set it belongs to.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The minifigure that you have is Kithaba from Star Wars:

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=sw397#T=P

it appears in this set:

[9496-1: Desert Skiff](https://brickset.com/sets/9496-1/Desert-Skiff)
[image]